# React Native 0.43.4: <RCTBundleURLProvider.h> file not found - AppDelegate.m

Tags: ios, react-native

`#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>` in `AppDelegate.m` in Xcode, give this error `'React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h' file not found`.

I have theise dependencies:

`"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6"
"react-native": "0.43.4"`

Any idea of how to solve this error?